# Ranger image preview not working on Iterm2

Tags: terminal, ranger

I could not make ranger preview images on iterm2.

I have set `set preview_images true` and `set preview_images_method iterm2` in ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf.
but a broken image appears.

Have anyone encountered a similar problem before?

[my rc.conf](https://gist.github.com/ChuanyuanLiu/c2740772c931ceeabd221564937cccd8)

[image: ranger error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's a known **bug** of ranger. Brew-installed ranger uses Python 3, and the source code of iTerm2 image preview integration in Ranger is broken under Python 3.

There's 2 pull requests try to fix this. But the development of ranger is stagnant and prs have not been merged yet.

Quick solution

```bsh
brew uninstall ranger

brew install laggardkernel/tap/ranger-fm --HEAD
```

References

- [iTerm2 image preview doesn't work with python 3](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1546)
- [Decode bytes into str for image display of iTerm2](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/pull/1604)